# Does network layer provide connection oriented service

Tags: ip, tcp, ipv6

I know that in TCP/IP model the data link layer provides connection less service.

While reading IPv6 Header. 'The **flow label** is used for connection oriented servie'.

[image]

How does TCP/IP model provide connection oriented service in data link layer.

It's a bit confusing.

Comment: "_How does TCP/IP model provide connection oriented service in data link layer._" It does not. The data-link and network layers are connectionless. Even many transport protocols are connectionless. For example, UDP is connectionless, while TCP is connection-oriented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow label is a (potentially random) number to help identify flows, ie. series of packets belonging together, not necessarily connection-oriented.

The flow label is placed in the IPv6 header so that networking devices don't have to look into and interpret L4 headers. It is not used for holding a connection together nor can it be used that way.

The IPv6 flow label is specified in [RFC 6437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6437):

> From the viewpoint of the network layer, a flow is a sequence of
> packets sent from a particular source to a particular unicast,
> anycast, or multicast destination that a node desires to label as a
> flow.  From an upper-layer viewpoint, a flow could consist of all
> packets in one direction of a specific transport connection or media
> stream.  However, a flow is not necessarily 1:1 mapped to a transport
> connection.
>
> Traditionally, flow classifiers have been based on the 5-tuple of
> the source address, destination address, source port, destination
> port, and the transport protocol type.  However, some of these
> fields may be unavailable due to either fragmentation or
> encryption, or locating them past a chain of IPv6 extension headers
> may be inefficient. Additionally, if classifiers depend only on
> IP-layer headers, later introduction of alternative transport-layer
> protocols will be easier.
>
> The usage of the 3-tuple of the Flow Label, Source Address, and
> Destination Address fields enables efficient IPv6 flow
> classification, where only IPv6 main header fields in fixed positions
> are used.